# Composer/Laravel: How to add the package moxar/ftp

Tags: laravel, ftp, composer-php

I need to integrate an ftp library on Laravel 5. I try to add this biblhothèque as shown in the link below. 
https://github.com/moxar/ftp
the problem I do not want to make an update to Composer "Composer update" I wonder how I can add only the specified package: "moxar/ftp"

Comment: You can download the library as an archive (zip or tar.gz) from [here](https://github.com/moxar/ftp/releases). But really, is there any particularly strong reason you don't want or can run `composer update`? Because you kind of need composer to enable simple class autoloading, and using Laravel and other libraries that are Composer dependent will probably turn our to be a hassle.

Comment: the problem is that I use Laravel 5.1 I fear that after "composer update" Laravel will be updated to its latest version and that's risk of my application malfunction alerady developed with Laravel 5.1

Comment: The latest version is 5.1.11 which is perfectly compatible with 5.1 so you won't run into any problems. Also you'll notice in your composer.json that the version of Laravel is locked to `5.1.*` basically 5.1.anything this means that if 5.2 is released in the future and you run `composer update` you will still be using 5.1 and won't be automatically update.

Answer (score 2):

User Composer require command.

```
composer require moxar/ftp
```